# Biasing SkLearn Algorithms to Positive Outcomes

Tags: machine-learning, bias, naive-bayes

I am trying to run multinomial naive bayes on a series of examples in python using sci kit learn. I am consitently getting all examples classified as negative. (The ratio of positives to negatives in my training set is ~1:3) Is there a way in sklearn to bias toward positive examples? I have coded it as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
X_train, y_train= load_svmlight_file("POS.train")
x_test, y_test = load_svmlight_file("POS.val")
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = clf.predict(x_test)
print('accuracy: ' + str(accuracy_score(y_test, preds)))
 print('precision: ' + str(precision_score(y_test, preds)))
 print('recall: ' + str(recall_score(y_test, preds)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `preprocessing` module in `sklearn` [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range)

Specifically see the scaling and centering features.

Alternatively, you could try setting the `class_prior` argument.